# Keyword-Highlighting of C++ using Listing

Tags: listings

I have a little problem in my settings. I cannot locate the error and need some additional eyes to tell me where I should look. I use listing to show my c++ code but when I try to add additional keywords they are not highlighted. Here's the setting:

```
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{dred}{rgb}{0.545,0,0}
\definecolor{dblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.545}
\definecolor{lgrey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\lstset{ 
      backgroundcolor=\color{lgrey},  
      basicstyle=\footnotesize \ttfamily \color{black} \bfseries,   
      breakatwhitespace=false,       
      breaklines=true,               
      captionpos=b,                   
      commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},   
      deletekeywords={...},          
      escapeinside={\%*}{*)},                  
      frame=single,                  
      keywordstyle=\color{purple},  
      morekeywords={BRIEFDescriptorConfig,string,TiXmlNode,DetectorDescriptorConfigContainer,istringstream,cerr,exit}, 
      identifierstyle=\color{black},
      stringstyle=\color{blue},      
      language=C++,                
      numbers=right,                 
      numbersep=5pt,                  
      numberstyle=\tiny\color{black}, 
      rulecolor=\color{black},        
      showspaces=false,               
      showstringspaces=false,        
      showtabs=false,                
      stepnumber=1,                   
      tabsize=5,                     
      title=\lstname,                 
    }
```

So nothing special, I guess. Here is an minimal-example using listing:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language={C++},caption={Caption}]
void XMLDetDecConfigReader::handleDescriptors(DetectorDescriptorConfigContainer* configContainer, TiXmlNode* descriptorsNode);
\end{lstlisting}
```

I don't want to use any other packages but to solve this highlighting-problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Output

[image]

I would heed Sašo Živanović's advice about defining your own `C++` dialect if you are going to typeset other codes in other languages in your document apart from `C++`. If not, then write `language=C++,` before `keywordstyle=\color{purple},` in your `\lstset`, then omit the `language={C++}` from your optional argument. You do this also for your own flavor of `C++` highlighting via the `\lstdefinelanguage` command.

Here is a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) completed from your code snippets. (Please post MWEs next time.)

### Code

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99455/keyword-highlighting-of-c-using-listing#99455
\documentclass[preview,border=5]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{dred}{rgb}{0.545,0,0}
\definecolor{dblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.545}
\definecolor{lgrey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\lstdefinelanguage{cpp}{
      backgroundcolor=\color{lgrey},  
      basicstyle=\footnotesize \ttfamily \color{black} \bfseries,   
      breakatwhitespace=false,       
      breaklines=true,               
      captionpos=b,                   
      commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},   
      deletekeywords={...},          
      escapeinside={\%*}{*)},                  
      frame=single,                  
      language=C++,                
      keywordstyle=\color{purple},  
      morekeywords={BRIEFDescriptorConfig,string,TiXmlNode,DetectorDescriptorConfigContainer,istringstream,cerr,exit}, 
      identifierstyle=\color{black},
      stringstyle=\color{blue},      
      numbers=right,                 
      numbersep=5pt,                  
      numberstyle=\tiny\color{black}, 
      rulecolor=\color{black},        
      showspaces=false,               
      showstringspaces=false,        
      showtabs=false,                
      stepnumber=1,                   
      tabsize=5,                     
      title=\lstname,                 
    }


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=cpp,caption={Caption}]
void XMLDetDecConfigReader::handleDescriptors(DetectorDescriptorConfigContainer* configContainer, TiXmlNode* descriptorsNode);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you do is define what style you will use and then by specifying `language={C++}` in the environment effectively undo your specification. Either omit `language=...` from the optional argument or, probably even better, define your own dialect of `C++`.